# How to edit a table column to accept multiple 'ids'

Tags: mysql, sql

Short background:

I am editing a video game that has four factions. I want to make all the factions enemies but only the 'arch wand' and 'crossbow' are enemies. Here is the code defining the clans in the clan table:

```
INSERT INTO `clan` VALUES ('1', 'Swordman Clan', 'Raffam Oranpere', 'prontera', '500');
INSERT INTO `clan` VALUES ('2', 'Arcwand Clan', 'Devon Aire', 'geffen', '500');
INSERT INTO `clan` VALUES ('3', 'Golden Mace Clan', 'Berman Aire', 'prontera', '500');
INSERT INTO `clan` VALUES ('4', 'Crossbow Clan', 'Shaam Rumi', 'payon', '500');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `clan_alliance` (
  `clan_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `opposition` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `alliance_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(24) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`clan_id`,`alliance_id`),
  KEY `alliance_id` (`alliance_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

-- ----------------------------
-- Records of clan_alliance
-- ----------------------------
```

Here is the code for determining who is allied to who and who is enemies with who.

```
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('1', '0', '3', 'Golden Mace Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('2', '0', '3', 'Golden Mace Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('2', '1', '4', 'Crossbow Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('3', '0', '1', 'Swordman Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('3', '0', '2', 'Arcwand Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('3', '0', '4', 'Crossbow Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('4', '0', '3', 'Golden Mace Clan');
INSERT INTO `clan_alliance` VALUES ('4', '1', '2', 'Arcwand Clan')
```

I run this in my workbench and get it in my SQL table. This works by default, but I am trying to edit this and make every clan an enemy of every other clan. Is there a way I can put multiple id values in the opposition field in the clan alliance table?

Comment: Your question doesn't really match the sample schema you've provided.  For example, the `opposition` field seems to be used as a bool flag (yes/no), however you mention wanting to load it with multiple IDs.  Also, what role does the `clan_id` field play?  What about `alliance_id`?

Comment: Why not provide the structure for all relevant tables?

Comment: The other table, clan, basically has what is in the first part. That is the only other table that relates to this. Yes I see that the boolean is what was confusing me, I thought the 1 meant clan id so I had to change my script to understand the new way listed below and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First normalize your schema.

You should have one linking table for alliances and one for oppositions.

```
DROP TABLE clan_alliance;

CREATE TABLE clan_alliance
             (clan1 integer(11) unsigned,
              clan2 integer(11) unsigned,
              PRIMARY KEY (clan1,
                           clan2),
              FOREIGN KEY (clan1)
                          REFERENCES clan
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (clan2)
                          REFERENCES clan
                                     (id),
              CHECK (clan1 < clan2));


CREATE TABLE clan_opposition
             (clan1 integer(11) unsigned,
              clan2 integer(11) unsigned,
              PRIMARY KEY (clan1,
                           clan2),
              FOREIGN KEY (clan1)
                          REFERENCES clan
                                     (id),
              FOREIGN KEY (clan2)
                          REFERENCES clan
                                     (id),
              CHECK (clan1 < clan2));
```

This assumes that the primary key of `clan` is a singles column called `id` of the type `integer(11) unsigned`. You might need to change the foreign key types and constraints if the assumption is wrong.

In older versions of MySQL (especially less than 8) check constraints don't work (they get parsed when creating a table but not enforced when inserting data). So you might need to create triggers to replace them there.

Note, that there must not be column for the clan's name in these tables. Such a column would be redundant, you already have the names in `clan`.

To then make all clans opposing each other you can use an `INSERT ... SELECT ...` self joining `clan` on the first ID being less than the second.

```
INSERT INTO clan_opposition
            (clan1,
             clan2)
            SELECT c1.id,
                   c2.id
                   FROM clan c1
                        INNER JOIN clan c2
                                   ON c1.id < c2.id;
```

You should also make it a habit to always explicitly note the targeted columns with an `INSERT`. Otherwise things could get messy.

Comment: Thanks this solved it, I had to change my script to understand the new way listed above but it works.